# virtual network service endpoint

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I have a virtual network in my resource group with the default subnet *Microsoft Storage* Service endpoints are already assigned to the default subnet of the virtual network but, now I want to add another multiple service endpoint with default subnet using PowerShell

The code below is what I'm using to add the service endpoint *Microsoft.ServiceBus* to the same virtual network.

```bash
#Get vnet
$virtualnetwork = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VN -ResourceGroupName $RG

#Configure service endpoint
Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SN -AddressPrefix $SAP -  
VirtualNetwork $virtualnetwork -ServiceEndpoint $EP

#Set configuration
$virtualnetwork | Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork
```

The issue is that every time I run the above script, it updates the current service endpoint rather than adding a new one. Any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and added the service endpoint successfully like below.***

I have created `microsoft.storage` service endpoint with default subnet like Below.

[image]

I tried to add another service endpoint`Microsoft.ServiceBus` to the same virtual network with default subnet using below powershell script

```bash
$subscription = "ID"
$subnets = @('default')
$vnetName = "your vnetname"
$vnetRgName = "Rgname"
$newEndpoint = "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
    
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription
foreach($snet in $subnets){
    Write-Host "Modifying Service Endpoints for subnet: $snet" -fore red -back white
    $virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetRgName | Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $snet
    $addrPrefix = $virtualNetwork.AddressPrefix

    #Get existing service endpoints
    $ServiceEndPoint = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'
    $virtualNetwork.ServiceEndpoints | ForEach-Object { $ServiceEndPoint.Add($_.service) }
    if ($ServiceEndPoint -notcontains $newEndPoint){
        $ServiceEndPoint.Add($newEndpoint)
    }

    $delegation=$virtualNetwork.Delegations

    #Add new service endpoint
    Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $vnetRgName | Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $snet -AddressPrefix $addrPrefix -ServiceEndpoint $ServiceEndPoint -Delegation $delegation | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
}
```

[image]

***Output***:
[image]
[image]

To check in portal, **`Microsoft.serviceBus`** is added successfully with default subnet along with **`Microsoft.storage`**.

[image]